# Best Practice for Reloading an Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

This is probably a pretty easy one, but I'm trying to think of the best way to tackle this problem.

I have a BookItem that I'm adding to a DB and have the following action:

```
//GET    
public ActionResult Add()
```

The user fills out the form and when they click "save" they post to this action

```
//POST
public ActionResult Add(BookModel model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("AddImage", "Book")
```

Which then redirects to another page, where a user can add an image.

Now, if the user clicks the back button in the browser, GET Add() is executed. The add book page is displayed, and is filled out with all the data the user entered.

If the user clicks save again, they will post the data and we'll have unintended duplicates in the database.

Seems like a simple problem, but I can't think of a nice solution.

I don't really want to use JavaScript...

It's an MVC2 app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think clearing the form with javascript once the DOM is loaded will be your only option (that I'm aware of).

Comment: I think you're right. If you'd like to answer this question, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe clearing the form with javascript once the DOM is loaded will be your only option (that I'm aware of).